# Meteor kubernetes more details on running it

Tags: meteor, kubernetes

Stuck on how to make it run. I followed everything on the http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/examples/meteor/README.html

I was able to build the image and push it to the gcloud. Now the problem is how to run it.

I accessed the ip that it gave me when executing the command

```
kubectl get service meteor --template="{{range .status.loadBalancer.ingress}} {{.ip}} {{end}}"
```

but nothing's showing up. Web page not available..

Answer (score 1):

Did you open up port 80 for meteor?

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create meteor-80 --allow=tcp:80 --target-tags kubernetes-minion
```